# Estimation of threshold vector autoregressive model

Tags: r, matlab, statistics

Does any function in R (or Matlab) for the estimation of threshold vector autoregressive model (TVAR) by OLS for a number of threshold superior than 3?

In [vgxvarx](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/vgxvarx.html) function, can I treat the 1st column of presample time series process matrix the threshold for my autoregressive model?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are such functions in [Econometrics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/var-models.html). Check out `help vgxvarx`.

Comment: Thank you, the thresholds are in the matrix Y0 of the presample time series process ?